# Kernel panic during EC2 launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

During deployment of new app version on new EC2 with template from AMI image I got following error:

```
[    1.670047] No filesystem could mount root, tried: 

[    1.670048] 

[    1.677170] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

[    1.685026] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64 #1

[    1.692532] Hardware name: Amazon EC2 t3a.nano/, BIOS 1.0 10/16/2017
```

previously it was working like charm - I haven't change any AMI or template setting - just added new SSL certs to nginx

I found this troubleshooting article but cannot move with it since I cannot access instance terminal.

I've tried to boo new instance with add different kernel ID but got this error:

```
You cannot launch multiple AMIs with different virtualization styles at the same time.
```

I believed during AMI kernel has somehow changed and it causes problem - is it possible?

What can cause that issue and how to solve?

Comment: Are you launching an Amazon EC2 instance from the management console? Are you selecting one of the standard "Quick Start" AMIs (which one?) or are you using your own AMI? What **instance type** are you selecting?

Comment: I'm building my own AMI image using Packer and instance type is t3a.nano

Comment: You might want to start with an existing AMI and then add your changes on top of it.